# VBA: ShowAllData method fails to work occasionally on a sharepoint located file

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I've created the macro which opens the file located on sharepoint. It's a pretty big and popular report so people work on it simultaneously constantly.

My idea was to prevent all filtering and hidden columns/rows from spoiling the layout and validity of imported data. Unfortunately from time to time code crashes with the error:

> ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed

I've made it read-only and I'm closing the file right after import. How this error can be eliminated? Is it because too many people are editing the data in "live" mode? It bothers me that sometimes it's working flawlessly and sometimes crashes.

Here's the part of the code:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Optimalization activated
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False


'Import from the previous file

    Workbooks.Open ("https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/teams/REPORT.xlsx"), ReadOnly:=True
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets(1).ShowAllData
    
    Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Dumpster").Range("A1")
    
    Workbooks("REPORT.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

    
'Input for output report
    Dim IRange As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
.......etc....
```

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: `If Worksheets(1).FilterMode Then Worksheets(1).ShowAllData`.

Comment: Hello. Does the .FilterMode deals with a hidden columns as well? Or filtering only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy all the data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim ar, addr As String
    ' copy from
    Workbooks.Open "https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/teams/REPORT.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        ar = .UsedRange.Value2
        addr = .UsedRange.Address(0, 0)
        .Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    ' copy to
    With Workbooks("Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Dumpster").Range(addr)
       .Resize(UBound(ar), UBound(ar, 2)) = ar
    End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Code looks really solid. I'll test it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Worksheet's Used Range

- `ShowAllData` will fail if the worksheet is not in `FilterMode`. `FilterMode` is read-only, therefore you need `ShowAllData` to turn it off.
- On the other hand, `AutoFilterMode` is read/write, so you can turn it off by simply setting it to `False`.

```vb
Sub ImportData()

    ' Source
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open( _
        "https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/teams/REPORT.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    ' Worksheet
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(1) ' don't you know its name?
    ' Clear filters.
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    ' Turn off the auto filter.
    'If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Show rows and columns.
    sws.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    sws.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ' Range
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange

    ' Destination

    ' Workbook
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("Tools.xlsm")
    ' If the code is in this workbook, instead of the previous, use:
    'Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    ' Worksheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Dumpster")
    ' Range (Cell)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' Copy...
    
    ' Copy.
    srg.Copy Destination:=dfCell
    ' Close source.
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```